# powerup asp tree events are not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview, asp.net-3.5

I am using the powerup asp tree (with my asp.net 2.0 web application) to show Location and department data. And this tree view have the check buttons also. In my code I handle the checkchanged, nodetoggle and nodeselect events. Its working fine with the IE browser, but when I try to check this in firefox it stops working even check is not maintained.

Any body please suggest me, why this happens and how I will take care of this in different browsers.

Comment: Please check if you have any javascrip errors, and it will help if you have a live version of it to see it

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue, but it may help other in maintaining old software.

The control may not be understanding Agent user string and incorrectly sets UplevelBrowser to false.

I was able to use reflection to set flag with

```
        if (!treeviewExplorer.UplevelBrowser)
        {
            // fix internal UplevelBrowser setting
            PropertyInfo p = treeviewExplorer.GetType().GetProperty("x754cb9503fcb8508", BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance);
            object x754cb9503fcb8508 = p.GetValue(treeviewExplorer, null);

            FieldInfo f = x754cb9503fcb8508.GetType().GetField("_b1ea521a985d430f", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
            f.SetValue(x754cb9503fcb8508, true);
        }
```

Comment: Could you explain the "magic strings" in your answer, please.

Comment: don't understand what is going here, but this fixed our rendering issue on Chrome.  thanks!

Comment: I'm getting an object exception when trying to use this code. Where exactly are you using this? Right at page load?

Comment: The issue is definitely with the control doing some internal user agent string parsing and doesn't know how to interpret modern browsers. I tried doing everything to make the reflection hack work, but nothing did. Ended up having to rip the whole thing out and implement the native .NET TreeView control instead. :/